# Print a pdf without pop up the AdobeReader window

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, process

I had wrote a code to print a pdf with C#. It's work but it's open me the window of Adobe Reader and i don't want it.

Here is my code :

```
 filename = "Doc1.pdf";
 ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
 psInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
 psInfo.Arguments = String.Format("/n /s /o /h /p{0}", filename);
 psInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 psInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
 psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 Process process = Process.Start(psInfo);
```

It's show me for 1 or 2 seconds the pdf at adobe reader and then show me the adore reader window without any pdf on it. I don't want to show anything. Just to print the pdf.

Answer (score -1):

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
psi.Verb = "print";
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.FileName = path + "/Invoice" + print + ".pdf";
Process.Start(psi);
```

Comment: there print is one variable which having int value to distinguish different different print when they put in for loop.....